# Determine all possible positive palindrome(s) numbers

Tags: mathematics, computer-puzzle, palindrome

> Determine all possible positive palindrome(s) **N** numbers, such that the
>   decimal representation of **2 x N^2** has no leading zeroes and contains
>   each of the digits from **0** to **9** exactly once.

Comment: [tag:language]?

Comment: @boboquack Sorry i was understood programming language.

Comment: wait....is it $(2 \times N)^2$ or $2 \times N^2$ ? yeah yeah, I know the order of operations. I just want to make sure

Comment: @Marius 2 x N^2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think they are:

> $N = 46464$ and $2 \times N^2= 4317806592$
>  $N = 69696$ and $2 \times N^2= 9715064832$

Explanation.

> The value of $2*N^2$ should be between 1023456789 and 9876543210.
>  This means that N has to be between $\sqrt{\frac{1023456789}{2}} = 22621.41$ and $\sqrt{\frac{9876543210}{2}} =70272.83$. Since N is integer it means it has to be between 22622 and 70272.
>  Wrote a little script that loops through all the numbers and checks if the number is a palindrome and that $2*N^2$ contains all the digits.
>  Here is my code. It can be tested on http://phpfiddle.org/

```
<?php

function isPalindrome($string)
{
    return $string == strrev($string);
}

function hasAllDigits($string) {
    $string = (string)$string;
    if (strlen($string) != 10) {
        return false;
    }
    $digits = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i<strlen($string);$i++) {
        if (isset($digits[$string[$i]])) {
            return false;
        }
        $digits[$string[$i]] = 1;
    }
    return true;
}

for ($i = 22622; $i<=70272; $i++) {
    if (!isPalindrome($i)) {
        continue;
    }
    $x = 2*$i*$i;
    if (!hasAllDigits($x)) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $i .'--'.$x.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: What about 46464 and 69696? 2*n^2 seems to return 4317806592 and 9715064832 for me.

Comment: @numbermaniac. Thanks for the heads up. In my defense, I said it's too early and I may have made a mistake in my "software".

Comment: @numbermaniac. Thanks. You are right. I forgot a cast to string.